# Virtual visitor

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I have a hierarchy of classes (`Base` and daugthers `A`, `B`, `C` and so on). The hierarchy tree is not finite. It’s possible to *visit* a `Base*` using the well-known *visitor pattern* in order to dynamically adapt to the dynamic type of `Base*`. The visitor has a type, like `BaseVisitor`. Like this:

```
struct BaseVisitor;

struct Base {
  virtual void accept(BaseVisitor &v) = 0;
};

struct A : Base {
  int a;

  A(int x) : a(x) {}
  ~A(void) = default;

  void accept(BaseVisitor &v) override {
    v->visit(*this);
  }
};

struct B : Base {
  float b;

  B(void) : b(314.f) {}
  ~B(void) = default;

  void accept(BaseVisitor &v) override {
    v->visit(*this);
  }
};

struct BaseVisitor {
  void visit(Base &) {}

  void visit(A &a) {
    std::cout << "just visited a A; a=" << a.a << std::endl;
  }

  void visit(B &b) {
    std::cout << "just visited a B; b=" << b.b << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Now, I’d like to make `BaseVisitor` an abstract class in order to inherits new visitors. The issue comes when I want to define the abstract class:

```
struct ABaseVisitor {
  virtual void visit(Base &) = 0; /* huh? */
};
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why not make `BaseVisitor` be abstract by making `visit(A&) = 0` and `visit(B&) = 0`?

Comment: the issue is the hierarchy tree is not finite (updating the post)

Comment: Do you mean depth of inheritance? How is it not finite?

Comment: well, because I don’t know all inherited classes, I can’t put them in the visitor

Comment: For this to make sense, you will need the visitor (derived or base) to treat all classes the same. If it needs to "know" if the class is a `A` or `B` class, then it won't work to use a virtual visitor.